# (IE9)Unable to get property 'dispatchEvent' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

My code is:

```
var internal= $("span[title='expand']")[0];
var clickEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
clickEvent.initEvent("click",true,true);
internal.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
```

and IE9 throws runtime error

```
Unable to get property 'dispatchEvent' of undefined or null reference
```

I am confused because IE9 starts supporting dispatchEvent. **But IE10 AND IE11 works fine with the same code.**

How can I solve it? Thanks!

Comment: The error is saying that `internal` is null or undefined. It has nothing to do with dispatch.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the local variable 'internal' is not undefined at the moment dispatchEvent is called?

Did the call to jQuery to fetch the span return a valid DOM Node?